# Temperature range for seasoning a carbon steel pan

Tags: seasoning-pans

I have this [pan](http://www.debuyer.com/en/products/mineral-b-element-round-fry-pan), but the seasoning that I created with [flaxseed oven method](https://www.cooksillustrated.com/how_tos/5820-the-ultimate-way-to-season-cast-iron) is very brittle and flakes off easily into my food. I have not been using anything acidic in the pan, so I think I just need to start from scratch.

Most information on seasoning is geared towards cast iron. I want to know what temperatures can I use with the carbon steel pan without it warping. Can I strip the old seasoning with a self-cleaning cycle or is that too hot? What temperature should I use during the reseasoning?

Comment: Hi, all of your questions are duplicates. We also have http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13555/what-oil-is-best-for-seasoning-a-cast-iron-skillet and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/641/whats-the-best-way-to-season-a-cast-iron-skillet to answer your points 2 and 3, and you can look through the rest of the tag as well. Carbon steel and cast iron use the same process.

Comment: @rumtscho ***Is*** the process for carbon steel the same as cast iron? The answer here seems to disagree with that statement.

Comment: @Catija I have never known of any differences, and can't think of a reason for them to exist. But see also http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56998, one says there is no difference and the other suggests a method which is typically used for iron too.

Comment: @rumtscho I don't have any personal knowledge of either process. All of my pans are stainless or non-stick, so I've never seasoned a pan in my life... I was mostly curious because it seemed like your comment and the answer disagreed.

Comment: I think they have a bit of a difference at how easy they are to season properly, but the methods are the same, you just have to be persistent until you have learned to do it right. We have a number of questions specifically about carbon steel too, and this answer is the first I've seen to suggest that a method cannot be applied to both.

Comment: Ah, I found another one about CS specifically.  Answers there seem to be the same http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/60037/carbon-steel-seasoning

Comment: @rumtscho I've spend some time with those questions before posting. Respectfully, I think cast iron is much more robust that carbon steel. I have warped a CS pan, and I have never done that to cast iron. Moreover, none of the other answers seem to give exact CS temperatures, which is what I am after.

Comment: OK, I see what you have in mind. The choice of oil still seems to be a duplicate, but the temperature is probably worth its own question. Although the existing questions already give hints for the temperature: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/54642 says 500 (F?), http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24520 "until the oil smokes". You can further fine tune my edit, of course, it's your question.

Comment: This probably won't help much, but I season all my pans (cast iron, steel, carbon steel and ceramic) pretty much the same way. Heat on the low end of high heat until a drop of water bounces when applied to the pan's surface. Remove from heat. Use a pastry brush to brush all parts of the pan interior with oil that has a high smoke level (I use grapeseed or avocado). Heat until any little droplets of oil skitter across the pan when disturbed. Remove from heat. Polish the interior with paper towel or a microfiber cloth, oil and all. Allow to sit open until any wet-looking gleam dulls/dries.

Answer (score 1):

For Carbon Steel seasoning I would rather use a gas burner until all of the cooking surface has changed color.  Then apply a high oleic oil either pour directly or using a rag/paper towel before allowing to cool.  This process could be repeated if desired.

If you need specific answers to the question you raised, it would be better directed to the vendor or manufacturer.